# How do you repopen a closed account?

Tags: anchor, pda, account, account-data, close

If an account has been closed with the following anchor context:

```
#[account(
        mut,
        close = user,
        seeds = [
            SEED_SCHEMA.as_bytes(),
            &user.key().as_ref(),              
        ],
        bump
    )]
    pub account: Box<Account<'info, Account>>,
```

Can it be "repoened" again, if invoked with `init` and the same seeds?

Or is it not actually closed and need to invoke it with `init_if_needed`?

Trying to call function which in its context includes the initialisation for the above account gives me  `account already exists` error, which I did not expect and am not sure how to solve it.

Comment: You can reuse the account, a tx with `init` and the same seeds will simply create the account again.

Answer (score 3):

The `close` attribute in anchor removes all lamports (SOL) from the account which basically frees/deletes the account.

After an account is closed, you should be able to `init` it as if it was never created before.

I've recreated your account and wrote a small test that initializes and then closes it. You can load the code linked below in [Solana Playground](https://beta.solpg.io/) to test it out,  You can re-run the test over and over again and it won't return `account already exists`.

https://gist.github.com/serbangv/75709c3a044d2a89f9b1121e89201ba2

So in your case, either the account was never successfully closed or it's returning the error about a different account you're initializing in that instruction.